# Possibly advanced SQL query UNION of 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Goal. To make a query that displays Product Name(Products), Product Type(ProductTypes), and total number of sales of each product(Sales)

Here are my tables:
[image]

I am having real difficulty figuring out how I am meant to do this. I am trying to do a UNION and a few other things but cannot get it to work.
I can get the total number of sales by using this `SELECT ProductID, count(*) as NumSales from Sales group by ProductID` but really struggling to do the rest and format it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

`Select Products.ProductName, ProductTypes.ProductType
From Products
INNER JOIN ProductTypes ON Products.ProductTypeID=ProductTypes.ProductTypeID`

I have this to display this right now, just need to join the sales count somehow.

[image]

Comment: join product table with producttype table and finally left join sales table select statement which you have mentioned

Comment: @ps_prakash02 Ok thanks for the response. I now have this to do what you said: 
```Select Products.ProductName, ProductTypes.ProductType
From Products
INNER JOIN ProductTypes ON Products.ProductTypeID=ProductTypes.ProductTypeID
``` Still kinda confused what you mean by left joining the sales table.

Comment: Start with any basic book or tutorial. It will become obvious to you that you do not need a UNION.

Comment: @Rick1990 now you have joined two tables (Product and ProductType) and the finally combine sales details to it. since all the product will not have sales info so go for left join. Select a.productid, b.producttype, count(salesid) cnt from product join producttype b on a.productid = b.productid left join sales c on a.productid = c.productid group by a.productid, b.producttype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
select prod.ProductName, ptyp.ProductType, count(SaleID) count_sale
from Products prod
join ProductTypes ptyp on ( ptyp.ProductTypeID= prod.ProductTypeID)
join Sales sal on ( sal.ProductID = prod.ProductID)

group by prod.ProductName, ptyp.ProductType
```